# flowtype - function param can only be one of the property values of an object

Tags: javascript, flowtype

I'm trying to use flowtype on my functions. I have the following example:

```
const operations = {
    create: 'create',
    update: 'update',
    remove: 'remove'
}

foo('create') or foo('update') or foo('remove')

function foo(op) {
    console.log(op)
}
```

`op` can only be one of the `values` in `operations` object

How can I change the `foo` function to work with the flowtype I need

Answer (score 3):

You can create a [union type](https://flowtype.org/docs/union-intersection-types.html#_)

```
function foo(op: 'create' | 'update' | 'remove') {
  // ...
}
```

**edit**

If the keys in `operations` always match the values you can do

```
function foo(op: $Enum<typeof operations>) {
  // ...
}
```

[see here](https://tryflow.org/?code=LyogQGZsb3cgKi8KY29uc3QgQ09OVkVSU0lPTl9UQUJMRSA9IHsKICBjcmVhdGVkOiAnY3JlYXRlZCcKfTsKCmZ1bmN0aW9uIGZvbyhjOiAkRW51bTx0eXBlb2YgQ09OVkVSU0lPTl9UQUJMRT4pIHt9Cgpmb28oJ2NyZWF0ZWQnKQpmb28oJ2xvbCcp)

Comment: I was hoping there was a way that would scale as I add new properties to the object and avoid using a union